# Error while using SQL query with DATEADD condition in R

Tags: r, sql-server

I am trying to extract data based on a date condition connecting to SQL from R. 
My database connection is from Impala.

Below is my sample code.

```
dbGetQuery(src,"SELECT * FROM sample WHERE eventdate BETWEEN '2017-01-31' AND DATEADD(m,1,'2017-01-31')")
```

I get below error while trying to query.

```
Error in .verify.JDBC.result(r, "Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for ",  : 
Unable to retrieve JDBC result set for select * from sample where 
eventdate between '2017-01-31' and dateadd(m,1,'2017-01-31') ([Cloudera] 
[ImpalaJDBCDriver](500051) ERROR processing query/statement. Error Code: 0, 
SQL state: TStatus(statusCode:ERROR_STATUS, sqlState:HY000, 
errorMessage:AnalysisException: Could not resolve column/field reference: 'm'
), Query: select * from sample where eventdate between '2017-01-31' and dateadd(m,1,'2017-01-31').)
```

Instead of using `DATEADD` if I hard code between two dates I get the result e.g.

```
dbGetQuery(src,"SELECT * FROM sample WHERE eventdate BETWEEN '2017-01-31' AND '2017-02-28' LIMIT 5")
```

I get the result for above code but I want to use `DATEADD` in my code because I have multiple date conditions which I am doing using a loop function.

Any help regarding this please.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the format of your literal date string (`'2017-01-31'`). SQL Server, when passed a literal string for date for `DATEADD` will implicitly convert the value to a `datetime`. `datetime` will read the string in the format `yyyy-dd-MM`, translating the value to `20173101`; you can see the problem there (there aren't 31 months in the year).

If you're using a literal string to pass a date(time) then use either the format `yyyyMMdd` or `yyyy-MM-ddThh:mm:ss.sssssss` as both are unambiguous regardless language and datatype.

So, for your value that would be:

```
WHERE eventdate BETWEEN '20170131' AND DATEADD(m,1,'20170131')
```

*On a different note, are you really looking for rows between `20170131` and `20170228`, inclusive of those dates (assuming `eventdate` is a `date`)?*

Comment: I am still getting the same error. If the issue is with the date format, then how come I get result for `"SELECT * FROM sample WHERE eventdate BETWEEN '2017-01-31' AND '2017-02-28' LIMIT 5"`

Comment: Because , I assume `Eventdate` is a `date` which treats the value differently.

Answer (score 0):

remove time from your DATEADD function by using `Convert` function.

```
dbGetQuery(src,"SELECT * FROM sample WHERE eventdate BETWEEN '2017-01-31' AND convert(varchar,DATEADD(month, 1, '2017/08/25'),23)")
```